# Two dimensional Arrays in Java

Tags: multidimensional-array, nested-loops

1. Write a program for warehouse, which can store the following two types of data

   • a unique number to identify an individual box
   • the length, width and height of every individual box.
   The box number which has been already assigned, should not be assigned again.

The programme should store the data for individual box while programme execution. It should store a maximum of 75 boxes.

The programme should offer undermentioned functions.

```
• Accepting new box through user input
• deleting the data of existing box
• change in the data of existing box
• display the data of the existing box
• one listing function, which should be able to display the data of all the existing boxes.
```

Deleting, changing and displaying of particular boxes could be done through the particular box number.

The following are the requirements for the implementation of code.

```
• Save the data in a 2-dimensional array. Create this array in the main method and no use of class variable for that array.
• Make sure while accessing the data of individual boxes, array length should be taken into account.
• Create a separate method for accepting new box through user input, deleting the data of existing box, change in the data of existing box, display the data of the existing box, and listing of all data of the boxes.
• Changing of data, deleting of data, and displaying of data should be possible only for assigned boxes.
• In the main method create an option to choose the individual function of the warehouse.
```

Comment: Can anyone help me in solving the question?

Comment: Someone will be more likely to help when you show some code that you've written to try and solve the problem.

Comment: Hi,  Shoejep  Thanks for the suggestion.